# R in a real time MS BI environment

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, sql-server-2016

Hope someone can help with the best way forward for a project I am working on.

My employer uses the MS BI stack - SSRS, SSIS, SQLServer, etc - and the developers have built a web portal in C# and ASP.Net to display real time management reports in a dashboard format. By real time I mean just that. As the underlying data changes, as it does many times during the day, so too does the information displayed on the dashboard.

I have developed a prototype dashboard with R and Shiny Dashboard running on an Ubuntu virtual server which is more graphical, interactive and includes reactive components and machine learning analytics.

Everyone is very impressed with the dashboard, especially the graphics (gglot an plotly) and management want to incorporate the analytics and graphical components into the existing portal thereby removing the reliance on Ubuntu and Shiny.  As it was only a prototype however it uses files that are created in SQL server and exported nightly as csv's into a folder shared with Ubuntu. From this folder Shiny/R reads in the files and produces the visualisations and runs the models on request. So far we have just created iframes that point to the shiny server but management are not happy with this approach.  They want to integrate the R models and graphics into the real time portal.

I know SQL Server 2016 bundles R services and we have begun playing with this, but how do you incorporate real time R analytics and graphics into the existing MS/.Net stack?

Cheers
Andrew

Comment: The simplest is to recreate your graphics in a powerBI R script, but there will be no interactivity

Comment: [Windows, Mac OS X, and other operating systems are not currently supported as Shiny server platforms](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/)

Comment: [Using Data from OLAP Cubes in R](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r-services/using-data-from-olap-cubes-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a good use case for shiny's `reactivePoll` function, which triggers a new data poll every time it's check function returns a different value.

You will need to write a `checkFunc`, which is a quick check on the SQL Server data to see if your data have changed. Then you will need to write a `valueFunc` that returns your app's data when `checkFunc` indicates that the underlying values have changed. And finally, you need to determine how often to run `checkFunc` with the `intervalMillis` argument.

This can get you to near real-time analytics using Shiny without having to rebuild it on another platform. However, if management is insistent on moving away from the Ubuntu server, this will not work.

You could try to rewrite your plotly graphics using plotly.js, and use a .NET trigger to re-run R scripts on the server as a part of the real-time pipeline to generate json data for your plotly.js plots, but you might as well just use `reactivePoll` to the same affect... Does management have a good reason for this request? It sounds like a lot of work when the analytics and value are being generated by R and Shiny, why try to fit a round peg into a square hole?

Comment: I seem to recall this talk https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/airbnb/ dealing with something similar.  I think they set up a scheduled task to export the necessary data to a CSV file on whatever frequency they needed and then used `reactiveFileReader` to pick up changes from the CSV.  It wasn't truly real-time, but could get pretty close.

Comment: Yeah, `reactivePoll` is like `reactiveFileReader` except it is for a database source or web source. You can quickly check something on in your SQL Server table like "last updated" and only download data/run your query if that cheap function returns a different result. If you are working in milliseconds, `intervalMillis`, I'd say that is pretty much real-time ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and will definitely look into things. The reason for wanting to move away from Ubuntu and Shiny is because I am a contractor and although I have fulfilled my brief in finding a way to make the user experience more visual and interactive as well as providing them with some analytical tools, they do not have the skill set in house either to maintain and administer the Server and R (and I think they're reluctant to train their staff which I have offered to do).

Comment: That makes sense. It would definitely be easier to train their staff than to remake Shiny and R in .NET. You could try to port the R pieces to https://www.opencpu.org/, which their .NET programmers should be comfortable interacting with.